# Parallelizing generation of random vectors with arbitrary length using numba

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

I would like to generate random vectors of the form

`[ i if random.uniform(0,1) <= probs[i] for i prange(K) ]`

for an `K` length array of probabilities `probs`. Each resulting vector has somewhere between 0 and `K` elements. Conceptually, this is like flipping `K` specific coins (with particular probabilities of being heads) and recording which of the coins displayed heads.

The arbitrary return length makes it difficult to use any of the automatic parallelization options in `numba`. E.g.,

```
from numba import prange, njit, int64, float64
import numpy as np

@njit([int64[:](float64[:], int64)])
def rand_coin(freqs,r):
    return np.arange(r)[np.random.uniform(0,1,size=r)<=freqs] 

@njit(parallel=True)
def rand_coins(freqs,n):
    r = freqs.shape[0]
    return [rand_coin(freqs,r) for i in range(n)] #                     **

r = 10; n =100
freqs = np.random.uniform(0,1,r)
rand_coins(freqs, n)
```

works great serially but produces a `double free or corruption` error if the `range` in the starred line is replaced with `prange`.

**Is is possible parallelize functions returning arrays with random lengths in `numba`?**

Answer (score 0):

`prange` is a numba function. The typing error is just a generic error from numba, saying that it ran into an issue while compiling the function. The real issue is that you are trying the make a call to a function that isn't declared. You need to utilize the `prange` function like so:

```
from numba import njit, int64, float64
import numba
import numpy as np

@njit([int64[:](float64[:], int64)])
def rand_coin(freqs,r):
    return np.arange(r)[np.random.uniform(0,1,size=r)<=freqs] 

@njit(parallel=True)
def rand_coins(freqs,n):
    r = freqs.shape[0]
    return [rand_coin(freqs,r) for i in numba.prange(n)] #                     **
```

Comment: That was just typo in my example above. Running your code produces a `double free or corruption` error (at run time with the toy example above)--is it working for you?

Comment: It works for be, but I suspect that it has something to do with the list comprehension. I looked it up on google and found this github issue: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3634. It appears that `prange` is necessary when you are using comprehension like that.

Comment: BTW: does the rand_coins.parallel_diagnostics( level = 4 ) confirm a parallel-section "around" using the np.random.*() where a strict-re-[SERIAL]-isation is a must, due to maintaining both the state-machine .seed and the reproducibility of the pseudo-random generated sequence?

Comment: @user3666197 When I execute the above `rand_coins` function I immediately get a double free or corruption error followed by a SIGABRT so I can't examine parallel diagnostics--most likely related to one of the two reports I made at https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4569